# Apple multitasking / split view resizing issues

Tags: angular, nativescript, multitasking, split-screen-multitasking

Is there anyone out there that has issues with the spilt view on iPads?

The app that I've published doesn't resize properly when using the split view on iPads.

But if I start the app first and click on all the tabs, then if I add another app in split view, my app resizes just fine.

To be able to use the split view I have updated the UIRequiresFullScreen to false in the info.plist file.

I'm wondering if it is something I missed when updating the app to allow multitasking and split views on iPads.

Thanks in advance

The navigation looks as follow:

```
<TabView>
    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: Tab1}" name="Tab1">
    </page-router-outlet>
    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: Tab2}" name="Tab2">
    </page-router-outlet>
    <page-router-outlet *tabItem="{title: Tab3}" name="Tab3">
    </page-router-outlet>
</TabView>
```

Comment: Do you mean, the app doesn't resize properly for split view while using tabbed control? Which component you are using - BottomNavigation Or TabView?

Comment: I'm using a TabView navigation

Comment: Is it your root view, app component?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. It is the main root view app component.